# VNC viewer through a remote MITM reverse ssh connection

Tags: ssh, remote, vnc

I am sorry if the title is wrong.

I have a raspberrypi3 that I am trying to view its windowing system with vncviewer from my laptop in a remote location.

I am able to ssh into it fine via an autossh service I setup at boot to connect to a mitm cloud instance of ubuntu. The ExecStart=`/usr/bin/autossh -M EphemPort1 -N -R EphemPort2:localhost:22 mitmser@x.x.x.x -o ServerAliveInterval=60 -o ServerAliveCountMax=3 -o IdentitiesOnly=yes  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o LogLevel=ERROR -F /dev/null -i /home/pi/.ssh/MitmUserKey`

So then from a laptop you can ssh yourself into the mitm instance , and then just `ssh pi@localhost -p EphemPort2` and you are instantly logged into the remote pi.

This works great, but I have never been able to figure out how to start a process on the remote raspberry pi and then have the windowing system forwarded to my laptop.

I have tried ssh from my laptop to the mitm with -AY
I have run xset + on the laptop as well

The mitm /etc/ssh/sshd_config has:

X11Forwarding yes

X11DisplayOffset 10

X11UseLocalhost no

The raspberry pi /etc/ssh/sshd_config has:

ForwardX11 yes

I have vncserver running on the pi , but then when I run "export DISPLAY=:0.0" and then vncviewer localhost:5901 via this ssh tunnel from my laptop into the mitm instance into then the raspberry pi it says: "vncviewer[5618]: CSession: connection error: connect: Connection refused (111)"

I then added "-geometry 800x600 -nolisten tcp -localhost" to the arguments of vncserver , from: [here](https://superuser.com/questions/564658/vnc-viewer-error-unable-connect-to-socket-connection-refused-111/564665#comment689163_564665) , then if you run "vncviewer localhost:5901" it appears to work fine, I can tell it runs and stays open , but it still never launches the windowing part of vncviewer on my laptop.

same for "export DISPLAY=:0.0" and then just running leafpad .
leafpad will run , and stay open in the terminal , but it never opens the window on the remote laptop.

any ideas how to view gui applications remotely through a mitm ssh tunnel ?